# Powershell Try, Catch: Why do we need Finally?

Tags: powershell, try-catch, finally

This strikes me a a supremely newbie question, but I can't find the answer anywhere in the googleverse. I've written some pretty complex scripts, but never figured this one out:

```
try { raise-errorCode}
catch { do-someThing}
finally {more-code}
```

versus:

```
try { raise-errorCode}
catch { do-someThing}
more-code
```

what is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

A `finally` block executes no matter the outcome of the `try/catch`. In the second example, `more-code` isn't guaranteed to execute. If there's a fatal exception and the program needs to exit, the `finally` block will always execute, while `more-code` in the second example wouldn't.

Comment: Example: Close database connection used in `try {}`